# Adding Array Contents Together in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, math

Trying to add the contents of an array together. 
`["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"]` the way I'm getting that info is with

```
c = Credit.last
c.payments.map(&:payment_amount).to_a
```

I'm trying to add up all the values together in the array.

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to add them together. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write it for you without you trying. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is a good read too.

Comment: If `arr` is your array, the sum of the elements is just `arr.reduce(:+)`. You should have been able to answer this yourself. Google "ruby summing elements of an array" and see what you get.

Comment: If his suggestion didn't work please be more descriptive than "That doesnt work".  You could for example say "I tried your solution but it gave me NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for "75.00" :String "  We aren't mind readers.  :)

Comment: My mistake. I didn't notice that the elements of the array are strings. You  need `x = ["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"].reduce(0) { |tot, s| tot + s.to_f } #=> 150.0`.  See the doc for [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`). If you want the result to be a string with two digits to the right of the decimal point, one way is `"%.2f" % x #=> "150.00"`.  See the doc for [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for formatting of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The other posters are correct in that your question doesn't conform to the how to ask guidelines.  The responses are not intended to put you down but rather to maintain the quality of content for stack overflow.  That said this should get you where you need to go.  IN the future please read the guidelines and submit accordingly.

```
 Credit.last.payments.sum(:payment_amount.to_f)
```

Comment: `:payment_amount.to_f` will raise a NoMethodError. `:payment_amount` is a Symbol and does not respond to `to_f`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may not have considered is that the array `["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"]` contains a bunch of strings.

If you were to sum them together like this:

```
["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"].sum

# or like this as one commenter suggested
["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"].reduce(&:+)

# or the long-handed version
["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"].reduce {|str, val| str + val }
```

You would actually get `"75.0050.0025.00"`.  This is because the individual strings in the array are getting concatenated together.

So in fact, you would need to convert the array to floats or integers first.  This can be done like this:

```
floats = ["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"].collect(&:to_f)

# or the long-handed version
["75.00", "50.00", "25.00"].collect {|val| val.to_f }
```

Then you can sum the values:

```
sum = floats.sum
```

**Edit:**

I just tried summing a string column via ActiveRecord and got an exception `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.:`.

```
payment_total = Credit.last.payments.sum(:payment_amount)
# returns ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 
# TinyTds::Error: Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum 
# operator.
```

Looks like that won't be an option for you.  Although, you could change the datatype of the column so that it is something other than a string.  If you change the column datatype then you will be able to use [aggregate functions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html).

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your help, i really appreciate it. i figure out a method through looking over couple of your guy's answers and putting it into one method.  `Credit.payments.map(&:payment_amount).collect(&:to_f).sum`